# Problema relacionado ao Vagrant ao executar vagrant up no mac os x

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Estou tentando trazer uma box para executar como sistema de teste porem não estou tendo sucesso, estou utilizando o mac os x yosemite e já instalei o virtual box e o mesmo se encontra no seguinte caminho `Applications/VirtualBox.app/` o erro que está aparecendo é o seguinte, ao executar: `vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox` executando separadamente está acontecendo o erro referente ao comando vagrant up:

```
  sh-3.2# vagrant up --provider virtualbox
   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
   ==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
  default: Box Provider: virtualbox
  default: Box Version: >= 0
  ==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty32'
  default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty32
  ==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty32' (v20150609.0.9) for provider: virtualbox
  default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32     /versions/20150609.0.9/providers/virtualbox.box
  An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
  message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
  again.

  Failed to connect to 2001:67c:1360:8001:ffff:ffff:ffff:fffe: No route to  host
```

alguém já passou por isso.

Answer (score 1):

O endereço `https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32` é valido mas ele está tentando acessar via endereço IP versão 6.

No meu Yosemite funciona com o seguinte Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
end
```

:-)

Comment: ainda não deu certo olha o meu arquivo http://codecor.com.br/certificados/vragrant.html

Comment: esse erro que está a acontecer agora. An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't resolve host 'cloud-images.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Você está tendo problema de DNS. Abra no browser este link:

http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/

Verifique se funciona no Browser para tirar a dúvida.

Comment: Você não é obrigado a usar o Vagrant. Uma opção bem mais leve é o Docker. 

      `docker run ubuntu: trusty` 

Já tentou com ele ?

Comment: está abrindo sim o endereço

Comment: não conheço o Doker, onde fica sua documentação

Comment: Para saber mais sobre Docker, veja esta issue aqui no StackOverflow pt_BR [qual-as-vantagens-de-usar-o-docker-em-lugar-do-vagrant](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72855/qual-as-vantagens-de-usar-o-docker-em-lugar-do-vagrant) ou visite  [http://joao-parana.com.br/](http://joao-parana.com.br/) onde você encontra posts sobre o assunto.

Comment: realmente estava com problema no dns, consegui executar a box