# Qual as vantagens de usar o Docker em lugar do Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, docker

Já uso o Vagrant e tenho ouvido coisas boas sobre o Docker.

Sou desenvolvedor de aplicações WEB. Qual as vantagens de usar o Docker em lugar do Vagrant num ambiente de desenvolvimento de software ?

Answer (score 10):

A manutenção de ambientes de Desenvolvimento, Homologação e Produção tem grande impacto no Gerenciamento do Ciclo de Vida da Aplicação (ALM - Application Lifecycle Management), devido a grande complexidade das aplicações. Para mitigar os riscos neste gerenciamento e manter os altos níveis de Qualidade desejados pelos usuários dos sistemas é necessário que usemos algumas das ferramentas disponíveis para os setores de Tecnologia da Informação que permitam alto nível de produtividade. 
Neste sentido é necessário compartilhar os recursos de hardware usando Maquinas Virtuais ou Contêineres.

Considere um sistema com 10 clientes. Considere também que ele tenhamos de manter três ambientes diferentes para cada cliente (teste, homologação e produção) devemos gerenciar 30 ambientes, cada um com seus ativos de software, banco de dados, scripts de teste, etc. 
Torna-se impossível usar maquinas reais pois teriamos uma pilha de 30 máquinas que consumiria muitos recursos e espaço físico. 
Assim devemos usar Maquinas Virtuais para facilitar o gerenciamento e provisionamento de serviços. Neste contexto entra em cena a ferramenta Vagrant que facilita a criação dessas máquinas virtuais.

A criação e manutenção de uma máquina virtual (Virtual Box ou VMWare) demanda grande quantidade de tempo e, por vezes, é complexa. Além do fato dessas máquinas virtuais consumirem uma quantidade imensa de espaço em disco e memória.

Devido ao crescimento da demanda por Maquinas Virtuais e grande dificuldade na operação desse ambiente surgiu a necessidade de melhorar esse modelo.

O Sr. Solomon Hykes, fundador do Docker Inc e atual CTO percebeu que não havia a necessidade de recriar um SO completo e bastava apenas reusar os recursos de um mesmo SO num espaço de run-time independente chamado Virtual Environment.

Ele lança mão de uma funcionalidade nativa do Kernel Linux para facilitar a criação e gestão destes ambientes virtuais leves.

Assim surgiu o software Docker que em pouco tempo roubou a cena quando se fala em automatizar a infraestrutura de software e hardware.

O Vagrant serve a um proposito diferente do Docker e ambos se complementam.

A meu ver a principal vantagem do Docker sobre o Vagrant é a quantidade de recursos usada por cada ambiente Virtualizado. O Docker usa muito menos recursos que as maquinas virtuais criadas pelo Vagrant, economizando espaço em disco e memória de uma forma avassaladora.

Com Docker é possível criar um WebServer em C ou em linguagem Go criando um contêiner totalmente funcional com menos de 10 MBytes. Eu mesmo criei um contêiner desse tipo fornecendo conteúdo estático via HTTP com menos de 6 MBytes https://github.com/joao-parana/docker-playground/tree/master/linux-solutions/prod, ou seja você pode rodar este tipo de contêiner até num Raspberry Pi de 512 MB.

Para saber mais sobre Docker, visite o site https://docs.docker.com/ ou http://joao-parana.com.br/ onde existem posts sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 3):

O Docker utiliza o sistema de containers do Linux, onde há uma instancia do SO que compartilha o kernel com o SO da máquina, já o Vagrant é uma Virtual Machine completa.

Fazendo uma analogia, Docker são containers em um navio e Vagrant seriam vários navios.

O Docker é um virtualizador de ambientes e usa muito menos recursos que as maquinas virtuais criadas pelo Vagrant, tanto em disco como em memória. 
Sua desvantagem seriam os recursos não estarem totalmente isolados por estar compartilhando o kernel. Mas na grande parte das vezes isso não será um problema.

Com ele a alocação dos recursos da sua máquina fica por conta dos serviços que você executará na sua máquina Docker. O espaço em disco também é muito menor. Nele é possível criar imagens realmente pequenas, baseadas no Linux Alpine, por exemplo, e ter imagens com tamanhos de 5MB~300MB.

Answer (score 2):

O Vagrant é para desenvolvimento. O Docker não se limita a isso.

A grande vantagem do Docker é a possibilidade de replicar o ambiente de desenvolvimento em produção. De forma automática e imune a erros humanos. Isso sem falar na economia de recurso para viabilizar esse ambiente parametrizável e altamente escalável.