# Docker vs Vagrant, quais as principais diferenças?

Tags: docker, vagrant

Recentemente tive um surto de interesse pela ferramenta **Docker**. Estou ciente que Docker e Vagrant são soluções de virtualização, entretanto, com abordagens diferentes.

Em meus estudo surgiram algumas dúvidas em relação ao Docker. De acordo com este conteúdo http://techfree.com.br/2015/11/container-vs-maquina-virtual/, entendi, que no caso do Vagrant é criado uma VM, já no caso do Docker não existe essa VM, mas sim um container que é executada como processo enjaulado.

Inicialmente imaginei que não teríamos um hardware virtual e nem tão pouco um SO hospede, entretanto, estou me perguntando: mas e essa imagem que é criada com o comando `Docker push nome_da_imagem`, não seria um SO hospede? E o Docker Engine, o que seria?

Obs: a imagem criada com o comando listada acima não é listada no modelo abaixo, logo me pergunto se ela é um SO hospede ou outra coisa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra dúvida: se falando de segurança, é mais seguro para o sistema hospedeiro ter um servidor web rodando como container ou VM? Me refiro a capacidade de um "processo" escapar e comprometer o sistema hospedeiro. Inicialmente imaginei que o Docker seria mais propenso a isso uma vez que compartilha o mesmo kernel.

Comment: @David acho que você não leu minha pergunta. Além das duvidas em questões perguntei quanto a aspectos de segurança em relação a estes itens, bem como questionei quanto a Engine do Docker. Veja que os contextos possuem diferenças.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual as vantagens de usar o Docker em lugar do Vagrant?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72855/qual-as-vantagens-de-usar-o-docker-em-lugar-do-vagrant)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Vagrant

Foi criado com o objetivo de se criar VMs pré-configuradas. A ideia de criar uma VM para simular ambientes e compartilhar com os seus colegas é ótima, mas é um problemão ficar horas instalando um sistema operacional do zero e depois instalando e configurando todas as ferramentas. A HashiCorp, organização que detém o Vagrant, bolou um esquema de tornar todo esse processo mais automático e prático.

Precisa de uma VM com Oracle 12c? [Pesquise no Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search). Possivelmente alguém já montou essa imagem. [O Laravel](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead), framework MVC em PHP, já aderiu ao Vagrant como método oficial.

Além disso, o Vagrant usa uma linguagem própria para manipular as configurações da máquina virtual, chamada [Puppet](http://www.jeroenreijn.com/2014/11/using_vagrant_with_puppet.html). Há também o [Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/index.html), outra ferramenta usada para replicar a configuração entre múltiplos ambientes. Ou seja, uma configuração basta para diferentes sistemas operacionais.

## Docker

O Docker nasceu de outra ideia muito criativa, e para ela, vamos invocar a figura da simpática baleia que é o mascote dela.

A baleia é o sistema operacional vazio. Cada caixinha é um segmento desse sistema operacional, que pode ser uma aplicação ou um conjunto de aplicações funcionando em conjunto.

Por que isso foi criado? Voltando ao mesmo problema do Vagrant, em que temos que replicar várias vezes uma VM. Suponha que queremos agora executar várias VMs ao mesmo tempo. Por que não usar apenas uma imagem básica de um sistema operacional e todos os outros processos usam a mesma imagem?

A baleia é isso. É essa imagem do sistema operacional.

Cada caixinha é um recurso que executa em cima do sistema operacional, ou seja, da baleia. Com isso, temos algumas economias:

- Espaço em disco;
- Memória de execução;
- Eliminação de redundâncias.

> se falando de segurança, é mais seguro para o sistema hospedeiro ter um servidor web rodando como container ou VM?

Ambos oferecem um nível legal de segurança, com restrição por controle de portas, como uma espécie de um *firewall* entre o nível hospedeiro e o nível virtualizado.

> Inicialmente imaginei que o Docker seria mais propenso a isso uma vez que compartilha o mesmo kernel.

Isso é verdade [apenas para o Linux](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#containers-and-virtual-machines). O Docker, em Windows e Mac, executa outro Kernel para viabilizar seus containers.

Cada imagem do Docker é direcionada a um sistema operacional diferente. Por exemplo, [temos a imagem do SQL Server do Windows](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows/) e [outra imagem do mesmo SQL Server com a implementação para Linux](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/).