# Ao gerarmos um container docker, estamos levantando uma máquiva virtual linux em background?

Tags: linux, docker, máquina-virtual

Um container necessariamente está atrelado a uma máquina virtual, ou ele é independente?

Comment: Não, containers são diferentes de máquinas virtuais. [Diferença entre VM e Containers LXC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96137/5878) | [Docker vs Vagrant, quais as principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205360/5878) | [Como “Docker” e “containers” (LXC, LXD) funcionam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166870/5878)

Answer (score 3):

Ao falar "em estamos levantando uma máquiva virtual linux em background?", se estiver perguntando se o docker cria uma marquina virtual completa rodando um kernel linux próprio e a aplicação em si a resposta é não.

O que realmente acontece é que o docker utiliza algumas diretivas do kernel linux como namespaces para isolar a execução de um container do restante do sistema porém todos os container executam diretamente sobre o kernel do host.

Vale ressaltar que esta informação é verdadeira apenas em sistemas baseados em linux, em um Windows, por exemplo, o docker realmente levanta uma máquina virtual linux e executa todos os seus containers sobre a mesma VM separando a execução de cada container utilizando a mesma estratégia de namespaces etc.

---

Estes links podem te ajudar a entender melhor sobre o assunto:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-underlying-technology

https://devopscube.com/what-is-docker/

https://forums.docker.com/t/in-docker-for-windows-does-each-container-run-in-separate-vm/19192

Answer (score 2):

O kernel do Linux está sendo trabalhado há décadas e as features de isolamento, consistem no kernel "mentir" para o processo em execução, de diversas formas.

**Container**

Em um container, o Kernel diz para o processo que ele está executando sozinho. Só ele e seus subprocessos conseguem se enxergar.

Em um container, o Kernel cria uma rede lógica virtual e entrega para o processo de forma que aparentemente, pelo ponto de vista do processo, essa "placa de rede" é só dele, e portanto o processo pode escutar absolutamente qualquer porta nela.

Em um container, o Kernel mente par o processo dizendo que o ROOTFS é um subpath no file system.

Essas "mentiras" fazem com que um processo no container tenha a ilusão de que está em uma máquina virtual.

Mas não passa de uma ilusão.

O Kernel é compartilhado entre todos os containers daquele host, assim como os processos (conteinerizados) são visíveis a qualquer processo que não esteja conteinerizado.

Esses recursos são recursos de nível de kernel, isso quer dizer, possuem além de alta performance pouca alocação de recursos para serem executados.

Outro ponto curioso, é que esse modelo faz com que tudo que o sistema operacional precise, só esteja presente uma vez, no host.

O container tem apenas binários (executáveis e bibliotecas), configurações, rodando junto (lado-a-lado) com os demais containers, sem saber disso.

A flexibilidade é que todas as opções de isolamento possuem configurações de exceção. Onde conseguimos compartilhar somente o que queremos, quando queremos.

**VM**

Em uma VM, o subprocesso usa features do Kernel e do Processador para criar uma infraestrutura toda virtual.

Isso quer dizer que dentro da VM será necessário um novo kernel, e por aí vai.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar do container ter a estrutura e aparência de uma VM, o propósito dele é rodar apenas um processo. Se vc precisa rodar um nginx, por exemplo, apenas o processo será executado dentro do container. Dessa forma, é possível testar ferramentas sem a necessidade de instalações no SO. Tenha sempre em mente que o propósito do container é processo.